# Svelte reference global variable inside onMount error

Tags: javascript, mapbox, svelte, mapbox-gl-js

So basically I initialize an object within onMount like this-

```
onMount(() => {
    
    const mapy = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9",
      center: testCoords[0],
      zoom: 19,
    
    });
    console.log(mapy);
});
```

Then outside I have-

```
function AddPoint(){
    Center=mapy.getCenter;
}
```

AddPoint is called from a HTML button.
I get this error in the console-
Uncaught ReferenceError: mapy is not defined

I only press the button after it has been initialized, and I know it has been initialized because of my console.log() inside onMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward scope error. When you declare `mapy` inside `onMount` (`const mapy = ...`), you make `mapy` *local* to `onMount` in scope, meaning it is undefined *outside* of `onMount`.

What you want to do here is *declare* `mapy` at the top level of your script, then *assign* to it inside `onMount`:

```js
let mapy;

onMount(() => {
    mapy = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9",
      center: testCoords[0],
      zoom: 19,    
    });
    console.log(mapy);
});

function AddPoint() {
    Center = mapy ? mapy.getCenter : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Omg I’m so sorry you had to take the time to do this, total brainfart moment from me :/